# What'd be the best way to make a rim?

Tags: mesh

So I'm making a lid to a jar and want it to have a slightly rounded rim that would visibly notch into the indent of the jar itself (think how a cookie jar's lid sits nicely) Though I'm unable to make a nice looking rim what'd be the best way?

I've tried extruding and scaling though that wound up insanely difficult to tweak due to the size of the tweaks (Should I just scale up the whole lid and then scale it back down when I'm done?)

I've tried making a bevel object but couldn't get it to line up not look right.

I also need to make an inside to the lid but that's fairly easy (to make it look like it has thickness)

What method'd be best for a complete novice?

Here's the model in question, if you want I could update with a version in wireframe/edit mode or add info if that'd help just tell me what you need to make recommendations!
[image: Rim]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this sort of thing is much easier to work in the flat, keeping the vertex count low, and working under a Subdivision modifier

So, I've made a nice pot, and a lid. But the lid doesn't have an inside, and needs to fit a recess in the pot.

- In Edit Mode <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> steal (duplicate) a profile loop, lying in the XZ plane, from the original pot, and <kbd>P</kbd> split it off into a new object.
- Do the same with the lid.
- Join the new profiles <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> into a new object.
- Assign a Screw and Subdivision modifier to the new combined profile, to make it back into a pot-with-a-lid.
- You can now edit the profiles in place -  if you don't show the modifiers in Edit Mode, you can flip back and forth <kbd>Tab</kbd> to Object mode to see how your work is going.

The picture shows the original profile in the vicinity of the rim, and 2 steps in the edit - using <kbd>E</kbd> extrusion on vertices to draw out new edges. Still in Edit, to make the inner dome,I created a new Circle mesh (unfilled) to add to the profile, moved and scaled it into the right place, deleted most of it, and <kbd>O</kbd> (Connected) proportionally edited it to keep it smooth inside. (Always keeping everything flat in XZ)

[image]

- You have the choice of if or when to apply the modifiers, add bevels, whatever you like.

[image]

In short, this recommendation is: edit the profile, not the pot.

Comment: I don't know how familiar you are with modifier settings and so on.. if you do try it this way, and get stuck, let me know.

Comment: I never heard of editing profiles before so I'm honestly not sure how this works I'll try it out and fiddle around so I might figure it out on my own but that seems easier than how I was doing it (Which was zooming in so close I could hardly pan the view)

Comment: @Jeff How did you make the pot in the first place?

Comment: Made a bunch of rings in a cylinder primitive and shaped them gradually that way, then I made another primitive to make the handle, duplicated it, rotated it 180 degrees and slid it into place after which I joined the handles and urn

Comment: by gradually shaped it I mean I mostly scaled them in and out to make the curve

Comment: OK, this is a whole different way.. 'lathing'..'spinning' using an outline and rotating it around an origin.  Blender uses the 'Screw' modifier, to do it non-destructively. I personally think, where you have non-trivial thicknesses, etc. it's an easier, and in the end quicker, way to go.. easier selections, moves, easier to edit after the fact.... in the profile, you only have to move one vertex at a time to change the whole shape.

Comment: Okay so I need to look into "Profile editing" "Screw modifier" "Subdivision surface modifier" and "lathing/spinning" I think (Based on both replies on my post) I figured I was doing my pot a really bad way that created way too many faces but since it's my first model I figured learning the software was more important than a perfect first try. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Jeff you probably won't find the phrase 'Profile Editing' but the other 3 are good. Typically beginner's modeling tutorials on lathing will start with making a wine-glass, or a chess-piece. Subdivision isn't the only approach to modeling, but it's pretty central. The 'Screw' modifier, as its name suggests, has the option of incrementally translating down an axis, and/or scaling,  while turning, but you don't want to use those here. Just turn. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85717/discussion-between-jeff-and-robin-betts).

Answer (score 3):

The basic way to do it is to extrude down the rim then create the inner faces with successive extrusions, and put some extra edge loops close to the rim to make it sharper.

[image]

To make it smooth give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, and in the *Tools* panel (left of 3D View) press on the *Tools* > *Edit* > *Shading* > Smooth button

[image]

Comment: Okay I want to give it a rounded shape so I guess I'll need to make a bunch of rings would scaling the model up to do the changes then back down work or are there problems with that?  Also how come your model looks so smooth with so few faces? Mine's a mess

Comment: I've edited my answer, you need to use Subdivision Surface modifier and Smooth shading